# Serving pages and HTTP STATUS codes

Tags: html, apache, security, http-headers, http-status-code-404

As all we know, when server gives HTTP 404 STATUS code, it can deliver some custom page. Which else status codes can serve some custom pages except 200-206 codes?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). The HTTP status codes and their definitions are listed beginning on page 56.

Comment: This RFC 2616 document covers only purpose of HTTP STATUS code. For me it is important to understand what can I expect from webserver looking from security perspective.